# How to wrap a huge static C++ library in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xamarin, static-libraries

I need to use a huge static C++ library in Xamarin.iOS project, I have only one .a and tons of *.h files. So I have to wrap headers with Objective-C to run Xamarin Sharpie tool. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Objective-C(++) is a superset of C(++), so presumably there is some way to make that work without writing any shims?

Comment: I would not go that way, I would use `CppSharp` to create C# binding : https://github.com/mono/CppSharp Xamarin (and other projects) use it for use-cases that match your exact use-case

Comment: @JustSid, problem is Xamarin Sharpie tool allows only Objective-C libs, not C++.

Comment: @SushiHangover, can I wrap any C++ lib (in my case .a and .h files) with this tool? I will definitely check it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it works any C++ **code** as it is uses Clang as a parser so the code must be compilable. It is a maintained project and does a great job, but it does require it bit of setup due to the LLVM, etc... the `premake5` system does most of the heavy lifting for you. I'd recommend following the simple examples before throwing a large library at it.... (I use it routinely on a game-engine to produce hundreds of c# classes with thousands of methods...)

Comment: But I have only precompiled .a file with headers, not code, it's an external lib.

Answer (score 1):

To acess the methods from native libraries, you use Mono's [P/Invoke functionality](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) which is the same technology that you would use in .NET, which is roughly:

- Determine which C function you want to invoke
- Determine its signature
- Determine which library it lives in
- Write the appropriate P/Invoke declaration

You can find the more information on this blog here: http://kerry.lothrop.de/c-libraries/

CppSharp is another option that is mentioned in the comments

Comment: Problem is I need to "Determine which C function you want to invoke". I have 100+ classes, 1000+ methods, I need all of them, actually I need just a wrapper (Xamarin Binding) for the big library.

Comment: Are all 1000+ methods need to be accessed from C#? Then CppSharp is the best way to go IMO. Run it on your library, and fix any edge cases one-by-one

Comment: Can I use CppSharp for .a files? I have no *.m or *.cpp files, just precompiled .a lib. It's not an open-source app.

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Let me talk to CppSharp dev, and update you

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know when you will have anything.

Comment: Or instead of .a file with headers I have .dll file with the lib. Maybe CppSharp can help in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I have .dll, .lib, .a files for a lib which I want to use from Xamarin. I hope CppSharp can help.